# Need help forming a LINQ to SQL expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Got a table with column names as such

```
Name | ProductID | Price | Category | SubCategory
```

I am passing a category name into an action method and I want to return the subcategory names that are on the same row as the category name that is passed in.

So something like this, except this is wrong:

```
var subcategories = 
      productsRepository.Products
                        .Select(x => x.SubCategory.Where(x.Category == category);
```

So I can then collect the distinct subcategory names with this:

```
foreach (string subcategoryName in subcategories.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `column names` when you talk about `row names`?

Comment: YEah, those are column names "Name | ProductID | Price | Category | SubCategory" And I want to pull out the subcategory names which are in the same row as the category name I am going to pass in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for:

```
var subcategories = productsRepository.Products
                                      .Where(x => x.Category == category)
                                      .Select(x => x.SubCategory)
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .OrderBy(x => x);
```

On another note, it does appear that your database isn't normalized.

Comment: No its not normalized at all or normal for that matter :) I am just experimenting. Normalized as I understand would involve me splitting that table into groups of related data by creating the following tables (categories, subcategories, products etc.) and then assigning products to those subcategories using a SubCategoryID primary key from the subcategory table and in turn assigning the subcategories to the categories likewise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the problem, but wouldn't you be better off filtering initially and then selecting the column?

```
var subcategories = 
      productsRepository.Products.Where(x=>x.Category==category)
                        .Select(x => x.SubCategory);
```

Comment: Of course I would, that did the trick. Thanks both of you. I just totally don't know poop about LinQ syntax and forgot that you filter first and then select from that result.